# Picture Doesn't Fully Send Over TCP

Tags: c#

I have a server & client model. The client is supposed to take a screenshot, and then send it to the server. The problem I'm having, is part of the screenshot is missing. What I mean by this is like 3/4 of the screen is black when opened in Paint or another app. When I send the screenshot command a second time, the file doesn't open at all, it's corrupt.

Here is my client side

```
if (plainText.Contains("screenshot"))
   {
      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
      Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
      graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
      bitmap.Save("test.bmp");
      writebuffer = File.ReadAllBytes("test.bmp");
      stream.Write(writebuffer, 0, writebuffer.Length);
   }
```

As you can see, it takes a screen shot, saves the image to a bitmap file, then reads the bytes into a buffer and sends it.

Here is my server side

```
foreach (user c in clientList)
        {
            if (c.RemoteIPAddress == currentRow)
            {
                NetworkStream stream = c.clientTCP.GetStream();
                writeBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("screenshot");
                stream.Write(writeBuffer, 0, writeBuffer.Length);

                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[0];
                readBuffer = new byte[c.clientTCP.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int data = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);

                string x = new Random().Next().ToString();

                FileStream f = new FileStream(new Random().Next() + ".bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                f.Write(readBuffer, 0, data);
                f.Close();
                Process.Start(x + ".bmp");

            }
        }
```

Here, I send the command to tell the client to send a screenshot, then receive the screen, and then write the said screenshot to a bitmap file.

I cannot seem to figure out what is causing the aforementioned issues in this code.

Comment: Is the protocol that you are using documented? If so, how does it say that the sender indicates the size of the file? And how does it say the receiver determines when it has the whole file? If the protocol is not documented, *stop* and document it before you write any more code. There is no way to know if your code is correct or determine whether the sender or receiver is at fault without a protocol document to define what constitutes correct behavior.

Comment: I think the problem isn't the lack of documentation, I think he doesn't understand why not all of the bytes are being written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's "answer" is useless. "hurr muh protocol". The reason your code isn't working is because the max size of a packet is 65535, and you're assuming the image isn't going to be any bigger than that - i.e you're only reading one packet. To read all the packets, use this loop.

```
while (stream.DataAvailable)
{
    data = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
    f.Write(readBuffer, 0, data);
}
```

It will check if data is avaliable in the stream, and read it till there's nothing left.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot seem to figure out what is causing the aforementioned issues in this code.

That's because you have nothing to compare it to. There are lots of correct ways to send an image and lots of correct ways to receive an image. But if you want your code to work, the sender and receiver have to agree on how to send an image. This is called a "protocol" and they should always be documented.

If you had a document for this protocol, it would specify how the sender indicates the size of the image. And it would specify how the receiver determines when it has the entire image. You could then check to make sure both the sender and receiver do what the protocol says. If they do, then it would be the protocol that was broken.

When you're using a network connection or file and you're not using an existing protocol or format, *document* the protocol or format you plan to use at the byte level. That way, it is possible to tell if the sender or receiver is broken by comparing its behavior to the behavior the protocol specifies.

Without a protocol, there's no way to say who's at fault, since there's no standard of correct behavior to compare them to.

Do not ever think that your protocol is too simple to document. If it's so simple, then documenting it should be simple. And if you think it's too complex to document, then you have no prayer of implementing it correctly.

By the way, it's possible to have a protocol for which your sending code is correct. But it's very difficult. It's impossible to have a protocol for which your receiving code is correct since it has literally no possible way to know if it has the whole file or not.

Comment: That probably would be a good place to start. I suppose I got a little bit far ahead of myself.

Comment: It will be painful your first time because you'll have to make every obvious mistake. But it will be worth it because it will be much less painful the second time. And a breeze after that. And it's invaluable when trying to maintain or debug your code, implement another client or server that interoperates, and so on.